# Can you reference/call Python Tools from a vb.net project?

Tags: python, vb.net, numpy, pvts

I've installed [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumPy%20and%20SciPy%20for%20.Net) in the hope that I can use Numpy functions in a vb.net project. I'm on vs2010, and this is not supported by the latest release of PTVS, on top of that the PTVS project is no longer support at all! To this end I'm looking to find out if I can use numpy in vb.net (using PVTS or otherwise) and if so how (an example of a basic Numpy call in vb.net would be perfect).

Answer (score 0):

IronPython lets you use both C# and Python together [try this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/657698/Python-Visual-Studio-and-Csharp-So-Sweet)